# Pass in the logical negation of a boolean to a partial template in dust

Tags: dust.js

I Have a partial template that takes a boolean, and I want that boolean to be a negation of a reference I have. So if my reference is `true` I want the value passed in to be `false`. Any way I can do this in dust without modifying the partial template?

```
{>my-partial}
     key=!value
{my-partial/}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing the js template helper I was using to pass in the intended reference